# Generate XML from regex matches

Tags: c#, xml, regex, string, pattern-matching

I want to read regex-matches like **@type/param** and generate a xml-file from the matches, as follows: **<type name="param">dummy#</type>** with the # symbol being a enumarated value, what would be the best way to code it?

**type** & **param** are variable alphanumeric values

Comment: I have trouble understanding on how to generate a new file from regex-matches and enumerating them at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so first get your matches as a `MatchCollection`:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(someInput,@"<your regex>",RegOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then create a file and XML writer, iterate the matches and generate the XML:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("output.xml",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None)) {

    XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(file);

    xml.WriteStartDocument();
    xml.WriteStartElement("Types");

    foreach(Match match in matches) {
        string type = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string param = match.Groups[2].Value;

        xml.WriteStartElement(type);
        xml.WriteAttributeString("name",param);
        xml.WriteEndElement();
    }

    xml.WriteEndElement();
    xml.WriteEndDocument();
    xml.Flush();

}
```

I'm making some assumptions like that your type/param are capture groups in your regex.

This *should* give you:

```
<Types>
    <*Type* name="param" />
</Types>
```

Comment: The MatchCollection-part is probably what I was looking for... the XML-writer part is a bit verbose. But definitly usefull

Comment: @userX You can probably tidy it up with something like XLINQ but I'm used to the old `*TextWriter` style.